# Is there a way to embed fabric dashboard in other dashboards(iframe)?

Tags: android, google-fabric

We have a fabric dashboard. the page is protected (requires login). I wanted to embed the link(iframe) of the dashboard into my grafana dashboard.

Can anyone help me?

note :
I believe if we get a sharable link of the dashboard from fabric , i can embed that anywhere but I do not know how to get a sharable link

Thanks.

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. We don't currently have a supported way to do this, but good to know you'd like to do it!

Comment: Thanks for the comments.   I think for now, I will need to manage more than few dashboards..

Comment: @MikeBonnell I realized your last comment was from a year ago.  Is this still not available to embed fabric dashboard into an iFrame of another dashboard?

Comment: Correct, we have not added this functionality.

Comment: I'm trying to create dashboards too, waiting for the feature.